# UILabel autoshrink is not working using interface builder?

Tags: uilabel

I made a UILabel and set interface builder properties as

```
LINES "0"
LINE BREAK "WORD WRAP"
AUTOSHRINK "MINIMUN FONT SIZE"
```

But whenever a large text is set on label, it does not shrink. Why?

Is there any other thing is needed to be set ?

Comment: lines=0 means it can be n number of lines long. instead give it as lines=1.

Comment: if lines = 1, if will shrink but only in one line, so it becomes very small, @ArmaanStranger

Comment: then try to give max lines by 5 or something..

Answer (score 3):

Auto shrink only works if you have constraints that fix the size of the label.
Either set a fixed "width" constraint on the label, or fix its width relative to its container, by pinning it to the superview.

edit: grammar is hard.